# Tooltip position in avalon editor

Tags: c#, wpf, avalonedit

I have a problem in wpf avalon editor, the position of the tool-tip is not set.

In avalon editor, I have to set tooltip near word when after word space is typed.
But I do not get any solution so that tooltip shows near word when space is typed.

```
toolTip.Placement = PlacementMode.Relative;
toolTip.Content = "aa";
toolTip.IsOpen = true;
```

Comment: I don't get what you meant by : *near word when after word space is typed*

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sample to do what you asked:

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:avalonedit="http://icsharpcode.net/sharpdevelop/avalonedit"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Window1" Height="450" Width="800">
     <avalonedit:TextEditor Name="TextEditor" KeyDown="TextEditor_KeyDown" />
</Window>
```

Code behind:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;

    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        private ToolTip toolTip;
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            toolTip = new ToolTip { Placement = PlacementMode.Relative, PlacementTarget = TextEditor};
            TextEditor.ToolTip = toolTip;
        }

        private void TextEditor_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.Space)
            {
                var caret = this.TextEditor.TextArea.Caret.CalculateCaretRectangle();
                toolTip.HorizontalOffset = caret.Right;
                toolTip.VerticalOffset = caret.Bottom;
                toolTip.Content = "aa";
                toolTip.IsOpen = true;
            }
            else
            {
                toolTip.IsOpen = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: WPF tooltip positioning at caret]

Comment: thanks this works but when there is scroll bar then again tooltip position not working

Comment: When there is no scroll bar does it work exactly as you want?